# Internal Server Error Zend Query

Tags: php, zend-db

Is something wrong with my query
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, @@ServerAdmin@@ and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

```
$sql = $db->query(
"INSERT INTO users (user_id, title, first_name, last_name, user_identity_id, email_id, password, office_phone_number, public_id, session_id, address_id, created_by, last_modified_by, created_on, last_modified_on, is_activated, is_deprecated, middle_name, cell_phone_number, superviser_name, superviser_email, superviser_phone_number) 
VALUES( :p_user_id,:p_title,:p_first_name,:p_last_name,:p_user_identity_id,:p_email_id,:p_password,:p_office_phone_number,:p_public_id,:p_session_id,:p_address_id,:p_created_by,:p_last_modified_by,:p_created_on,:p_last_modified_on,:p_is_activated,:p_is_deprecated,:p_middle_name,:p_cell_phone_number,:p_superviser_name,:p_superviser_email,:p_superviser_phone_number)",
array(
'p_user_id' => '',
'p_title' => $title,
'p_first_name' => $first_name,
'p_last_name' => $last_name,
'p_user_identity_id' => '',
'p_email_id' => $email,
'p_password' => $pass,
'p_office_phone_number' => $office_ph_no,
'p_public_id' => '',
'p_session_id' => '',
'p_address_id' => '',
'p_created_by' => '',
'p_last_modified_by' => '',
'p_created_on' => '',
'p_last_modified_on' => '',
'p_is_activated' => '',
'p_is_deprecated' => '',
'p_middle_name' => $middle_name,
'p_cell_phone_number' => $cell_ph_no,
'p_superviser_name' => $supervisor_name,
'p_superviser_email' => $supervisor_email,
'p_superviser_phone_number' => $supervisor_ph_no
)
);
$db->commit();
```

Comment: Please take a look at error log and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you're trying to execute a PDO statement using named parameters in Zend.

First thing to check, I assume you've started a transaction?

Also, in my experience named parameters are the same in the query as in the params array, e.g. :param1 is `$params = array(':param1'=>'data');`

I use the same method as described in the ZF docs ["executing a statement using named parameters"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html#zend.db.statement.executing):

```
$select = 'select col1,col2 from my_table where con1=:param1 and con2=:param2';
$params = array(
    ':param1'=> 'somedata',
    ':param2'=> 'someotherdata'
);
$statement = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($db,$sql);
if($statement->execute($params)){
    //ok!
}
```